# pip fails to find any packages from requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi, requirements.txt

I have a `requirements.txt` file with following packages listed:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
APScheduler==3.3.1
asn1crypto==0.22.0
bcrypt==3.1.3
boto3==1.4.4
botocore==1.5.72
```

When I do a `pip install -q -U -r requirements.txt`; I receive following error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement appdirs==1.4.3
>   (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for appdirs==1.4.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line
>   1))

But, the following works:

```
$ pip install appdirs
Collecting appdirs
  Downloading appdirs-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: appdirs
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.3
```

Once I had manually installed appdirs, I tried running from requirements again:

```
$ pip install -q -U -r requirements.txt
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement APScheduler==3.3.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for APScheduler==3.3.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

I tried specifying the exact version for the next command now:

```
$ pip install APScheduler==3.3.1           
Collecting APScheduler==3.3.1
  Downloading APScheduler-3.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 2.8MB/s 
Collecting tzlocal>=1.2 (from APScheduler==3.3.1)
  Downloading tzlocal-1.4.tar.gz
Collecting funcsigs; python_version == "2.7" (from APScheduler==3.3.1)
  Downloading funcsigs-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.4.0 (from APScheduler==3.3.1)
  Downloading six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz (from APScheduler==3.3.1)
  Downloading pytz-2017.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (484kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 491kB 2.2MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=0.7 in ./.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from APScheduler==3.3.1)
Collecting futures; python_version == "2.7" (from APScheduler==3.3.1)
  Downloading futures-3.1.1-py2-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: tzlocal
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for tzlocal ... done
  Stored in directory: $HOME/.cache/pip/wheels/dc/d6/f0/84194ccbdd3e2551bdb207e1fc1925efd32956c5767328103b
Successfully built tzlocal
Installing collected packages: pytz, tzlocal, funcsigs, six, futures, APScheduler
Successfully installed APScheduler-3.3.1 funcsigs-1.0.2 futures-3.1.1 pytz-2017.2 six-1.11.0 tzlocal-1.4
```

How is pip not able to find the packages if specifying the `requirements` file? And why does it keep finding the same packages without it?

PS: Everything is being done inside a **`virtualenv`** named `.env`.

---

```
$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from $PWD/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
$ python -V
Python 2.7.13
$ which python
$PWD/.env/bin/python
```

---

Doing a `pip --verbose` command gives:

```
Collecting asn1crypto==0.22.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  1 location(s) to search for versions of asn1crypto:
  * https://pip.<domain>/asn1crypto/
  Getting page https://pip.<domain>/asn1crypto/
  Looking up "https://pip.<domain>/asn1crypto/" in the cache
  No cache entry available
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pip.<domain>
  "GET /asn1crypto/ HTTP/1.1" 303 0
  Status code 303 not in [200, 203, 300, 301]
  Looking up "https://pip.<domain>/simple/asn1crypto/" in the cache
  No cache entry available
  "GET /simple/asn1crypto/ HTTP/1.1" 303 0
  Status code 303 not in [200, 203, 300, 301]
  Starting new HTTP connection (1): pypi.python.org
  "GET /simple/asn1crypto/ HTTP/1.1" 403 16
  Could not fetch URL https://pip.<domain>/asn1crypto/: 403 Client Error: SSL is required for url: http://pypi.python.org/simple/asn1crypto/ - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement asn1crypto==0.22.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for asn1crypto==0.22.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
```

where `https://pip.<domain>` is our custom hosted [pypi-server layer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `fallback_url` on your pypi server to an `https` URL because `pypi.python.org` now only allows https requests. See [this link (python mailing list)](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-October/031712.html) for more information.

Comment: But the same settings were working for past year. It started behaving differently since today. The pip/python versions have not been changed.

Comment: @hjpotter92 there is pull request in pypiserver to fix this:
https://github.com/pypiserver/pypiserver/pull/182